# How to Divide each element by vector

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Days = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Values = c(100L, 99L, 98L, 100L, 
99L, 98L, 100L, 99L, 98L)), .Names = c("Names", "Days", "Values"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "Master"), Days = 1:10, 
    Values = c(100L, 99L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 
    91L)), .Names = c("Names", "Days", "Values"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a data table with values corresponding to each day for each particular sample.  I have another data table that is the master value to compare each day against.  I would like to divide each day by the corresponding day from the master table.

The desired output would be percent value.

Comment: You may need a join `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[df2, div := Values/i.Values, on = .(Days)]` or with `match` from `base R` i.e. `df1$Values/df2$Values[match(df1$Days, df2$Days)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x    <- structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Days = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Values = c(100L, 99L, 98L, 100L, 99L, 98L, 100L, 99L, 98L)), .Names = c("Names", "Days", "Values"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
mstr <- structure(list(Names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "Master"), Days = 1:10, Values = c(100L, 99L, 98L, 97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 91L)), .Names = c("Names", "Days", "Values"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Base R:

We don't need `Names` from the latter, and I prefer to have the field names not collide (causing them both to be suffixed with `.x` and `.y`), so I'll rename `Values`:

```
mstr <- mstr[-1]
colnames(mstr)[2] <- "mVal"
```

A straight-forward merge brings `Values` along-side the master's `Values` (now `mVal`), so you can do whatever math you need as straight vectors:

```
y <- merge(x, mstr[-1], by = "Days", all.x = TRUE)
y
#   Days Names Values mVal
# 1    1     A    100  100
# 2    1     C    100  100
# 3    1     B    100  100
# 4    2     A     99   99
# 5    2     B     99   99
# 6    2     C     99   99
# 7    3     B     98   98
# 8    3     A     98   98
# 9    3     C     98   98
y$newVal <- y$Values / y$mVal
y
#   Days Names Values mVal newVal
# 1    1     A    100  100      1
# 2    1     C    100  100      1
# 3    1     B    100  100      1
# 4    2     A     99   99      1
# 5    2     B     99   99      1
# 6    2     C     99   99      1
# 7    3     B     98   98      1
# 8    3     A     98   98      1
# 9    3     C     98   98      1
```

(I'm assuming that all `Days` in `x` are present in `mstr`.)

## `dplyr`

Using the original/unmodified `x` and `mstr` above:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x, select(mstr, Days, mVal = Values), by = "Days")
```

gets you to the same point as `merge`. (You could have pre-conditioned `mstr` as I did in the base R code, but I thought I'd show it mid-step here as an alternative.)

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks!

Comment: If this completely addresses your question, please "accept" it by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer. (It's nice to provide closure to the question, as well as a small "thanks" to the answerer.)